# listbox control of windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
            <ListBoxItem Content="A " />
        </ListBox>
```

-> above is my listbox in xaml file

-> how to change the visibility of Listbox item "A" programmatically using itself only

Comment: i mean change visibility without using its index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(list.Items[0] as ListBoxItem).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

You forgot about cast

Comment: its giving NullReferenceException 
the Visibility "A" i.e. first item is "collapsed" 
and it has to be made visible

Comment: sorry ,its not giving exception, thnx a lot